# Can't see animation when using jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

so I know this question has been asked many times, but I could not find any answer that works for me. I've already included the jQuery Google API line before my script, and I'm pretty sure my syntax is correct as far as I know (since I'm following a tutorial video for this). I've also added a few lines of console.log() in some places and I know for sure that it is going pass the animate function and reaching the end of the code. Here is my code:

index.html (Not all, just a small part to show that I have the API included)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

javascript.js (Also not all, just the part I'm having problem with)

```
prepareToAttack = function () {
    $("#pikachu-img").animate({
        top: "-=25px"
    }, 200, function () {
        $("#pikachu-img").animate({
            top: "+=25px"
        }, 200);
    });
};
```

Back to index.html (This is where the pikachu image is set up)

```
<img id="pikachu-img "src="img/pikachu.png" class="absolute" style="height: 115px; top: 40px; right: 46px">
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm not seeing the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem caused by img tag, your double quote of id stick with src.

No other problem found in my test:

**NOTE:** Using the style attribute in HTML is bad practice. Use plain CSS instead! Remember when an elements CSS in dynamically manipulated say `whatever.style.color = "red"` it will add the style attribute, then and only then it should be used.

Also thanks to HTML5 [you can scrap the `type="text/javascript"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) on your `script` tag.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="pikachu-img" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtDxj0kmEFUVNCUDF4G6553Hm-1w_ADcyYKhpkQf7pfsusCpHsbYpS3bQm">
```

**CSS:**

```
.pikachu-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 115px;
  top: 40px;
  right: 46px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $("#pikachu-img").animate({
    top: "-=25px"
  }, 2000, function() {
    $("#pikachu-img").animate({
      top: "+=25px"
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```